# Some useful information on DB2 Partitioning

Tags: db2, database-partitioning

This is regarding to the question that I asked few weeks back. [Link]
[DB2 Partitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979684/db2-partitioning?noredirect=1#comment36985105_23979684) , I asked how and where to check the partition key values in DB2.

After a bit of research I finally figure it out and want to share this information with others, I hope it may come useful to others.

How to see this key values ?
=> For LUW (Linux/Unix/Windows) you can see the keys in the Table Object Editor or the Object Viewer Script tab.
For z/OS there is an Object Viewer tab called "Limit Keys". I've opened issue TDB-885 to create an Object Viewer tab for LUW tables.

A simple query to check this values:

SELECT * FROM SYSCAT.DATAPARTITIONS

WHERE TABSCHEMA = ? AND TABNAME = ?

ORDER BY SEQNO

reference: 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0021353.html?lang=en

Thanks

Comment: ...Except this isn't a question.  This should be posted as answer to your original question (answering your own questions is fine).  Keep in mind you should also format provide replacement strings for URLs (especially ones like that), and otherwise make the answer neater.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question - it is an answer to an existing (open) question the OP posted.

Comment: Yes this is the answer for a question that I asked previously. I just shared this information so it might come useful to somebody else.

Thanks

Comment: And this seems more of a topic for [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)